# How can we store password other than plain text?

Tags: linux, security, authentication

I've found numerous posts on stackoverflow on how to store user passwords. However, I need to know what is the best way to store a password that my application needs to communicate with another application via the web? Currently, our web app needs to transmit data to a remote website. To upload the data, our web app reads the password from a text file and creates the header with payloads and submits via https.

This password in plain text on the file system is the issue. Is there any way to store the password more securely?

This is a linux os and the application is written in python and is not compiled.

Further clarification:
There are no users involved in this process at all. The password stored in the file system is used by the other web app to authenticate the web app that is making the request. To put it in the words of a commenter below:
"In this case, the application is the client to another remote application."

Comment: What languages/technologies are you using for the upload?

Comment: I have one other question: do you have control over the webapp to which you transmit the data ? Because a Sign Scheme (where your app signs and the webapp checks the sign) seems better than sending a password... although you would still have to store the signing key, but hey there are applications do help with that (google czar comes to mind)

Comment: Yes, both web applications are in our control... that is to say, we program both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the question it seems you need to store password in such a way, that it can be read and used in an automated transaction with another site. You could encrypt the password and store it encrypted in the file, then decrypt it using a key stored elsewhere in your system before using it. This makes difficulties to someone that gets access to the file from using the password, as they now have to find the key and encryption algorithm used, so they can decrypt it.

As defense, more lesser defense is always better than one strong defense that fails when breached. Moreover, I would also secure the file containing the password, rather than the password itself. Configure your webserver to disable possibility to serve the file containing the password, and try to set the process needing the file to run under a separate account, so you can restrict the access to the file to account running the process and admin accounts only.

Comment: +1 for encrypting the password within the file, and decrypting when used - I should have included this in the list in my answer.

Comment: Can you tell me which method you would use to encrypt the password so that I can then also decrypt it when needed? Thanks!

Comment: -1 this is not a problem that cryptography solves.   The attacker will be able to obtain the key as easily as the password that its trying to protect.  This is a job for file privilege and user access control.

Comment: Agree with @Rook - this is not a secure solution. If you are encrypted passwords are compromised, getting the key is easy. File system protection won't help, because whatever you do, the webserver needs access to the password. If the webserver has access, so does a potential attacker.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I think it is a valuable part of a defense in depth strategy. If the encryption key is stored in a different place than the password file, and both are in a different place than the process which uses them, an attacker has more steps to take before causing any damage.

Comment: @TheRook / @Sri There is no *one* solution to this problem, however by encrypting the password you make it such that an attacker must find more than 1 piece of the puzzle. As noted in the second paragraph my recommendations also encompassed the use of UAC (and I probably should have noted this would be my preferred approach if only 1 were selected).

Comment: @Eric Any encryption algorithm that your crypto libraries support, so long as it is an encryption algorithm and not a hashing algorithm.

Comment: @sri not a complete solution,  but the file should only be accessible by the application `chmod 500`.

Comment: SO, basically you need to store the password_key in plan text in different place and limit it access to that particular application, right??

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will find a foolproof way to do this. I would suggest a combination of things to achieve 'security by obscurity':

- store the password file on a different computer than the one which will use it
- store the file path in a separate config file on the app nachine
- use permissions to limit access to the config and password files to your process only
- audit file access if your system allows it (keep a log of who touched the files)
- give the folders and files innocuous names (/usr/joe/kittens.txt?)
- block physical access to the computer(s) (offsite hosting, or locked closet, or something)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-way key encryption algorithms like RSA,
The password is stored encrypted (by a key, which is stored in the user's brain) on the filesystem, but to decode the password, the user must enter the key.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. This is an automated process of sending the data to the remote server. There will be no person in the middle to type anything. Did I misunderstand? Thx

Comment: It has the issue of the user having to provide an input himself, but no method can be really secure and avoid this (if the application can retrieve the password without user interaction, then anyone able to reverse-engineer the application can too).

Comment: This does not solve, but only relay the problem. The follow-up question would be: how to store the key required to decrypt the password?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you should use permissions (if you are on a filesystem which supports them) to ensure that you are the only one able to read the file.

In addition, if your app is compiled, it would not be too difficult to encrypt the password with a hard-coded passphrase. If the code is not compiled this method wouldn't really be helpful, as a would-be attacker could just read the source and determine the encryption.

Comment: This is a linux based OS. And, this application is not compiled. Thanks for the permissions suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

Is your web application hosted on a farm? If not then a technology such as [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) will allow you to encrypt the password so that it can only be decrypted on the machine it was encrypted on.

From memory there can be problems with using it on a web farm though, as you need to go and re-encrypt the value for each server.

If it is a web farm then you probably want to use some form of RSA encryption as has been suggested in other answers.

EDIT: DPAPI is only good if you are hosting on windows of course...

Answer (score -3):

[Protecting the Automatic Logon Password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378826.aspx)

The LsaStorePrivateData function can be used by server applications to store client and machine passwords.

Windows only